# Ubuntu 17.10 black screen in VM

Tags: boot, drivers, virtualbox, 17.10

I am running Ubuntu 17.10 in virtualbox.  It was working fine but now when I turn it on it says "recovering journal" and then comes up messages about removing orphaned inode.  The screen then goes black and the window keeps re-sizing.

From Googling about it seem like it might be a driver issue with an update and the advice given is to boot into the command line and remove graphic drivers but how do I get to the command line?  It just gives black screen.

I tried the boot cd and it works fine, I an still see all my files but how can I get to command line in the actual installed ubuntu to remove the drivers to see if that fixes issue?

edit: i discovered recovery console and tried fixing packages but still same issue.  Is it possible to install ubuntu again but retain my files?  I dont have any backups or snapshots

Comment: Boot Ubuntu 17.10 to an earlier snapshot if you saved one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now working if you install the new version of the Guest Additions.
For 5.2.6: https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.2.7-120528.iso
For 5.1.32: https://www.virtualbox.org/download/testcase/VBoxGuestAdditions_5.1.33-120529.iso
Make sure you switch from Wayland to Xorg if you want 3D acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when Virtualbox Restricted driver was enabled + 3D acceleration was disabled within VirtualBox. To fix I enabled 3D acceleration, logged into unity, disable Virtualbox 3D driver in Additional Drivers, shutdown, disabled 3D acceleration and booted up again with no issues.