# Firefox slow down Ubuntu 17.10 as Virtualbox guest

Tags: virtualbox, firefox, 17.10

I am testing Ubuntu 17.10 Desktop as a Virtualbox 5.2 guest. The Virtualbox guest additions are installed from Virtualbox Addition ISO. Virtualbox itself is running on a Ubuntu 16.04 host.

After a first view everything works fine. But as soon as I start the Firefox browser any application windows are frozen for several seconds. There are no special activities in the system visible, nor is there any warning or error in syslog.

The "frozen" situation stays also, when I kill the firefox process. After system reboot everything works fine as long as I start Firefox again.

Working with Chromium does not cause any problems.

Any ideas what I can do to solve that problem or what I can check?

Comment: Perhaps Firefox is using too much memory for some reason.

Comment: Yea firefox is slow. Try another browser perhaps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem becomes only active when the Virtualbox guest 3D mode is enabled. When I disable the 3D mode, the guest is working as desired, also when Firefox browser is started.

Comment: Ubuntu 17.10 with 3d acceleration disable works many times slower than Ubuntu 16.04 with 3d acceleration enabled.

Comment: This is worked for Ubuntu 16.04 on macOS host.

Answer (score 0):

This is now working with the new version of the Guest Additions released: Check my answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1006002/6919